# Using a smooth scroll snippet, center element in page

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, anchor, smooth-scrolling

I am using this script.

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

It is working well, except for one thing. When I click on the anchor, and get scrolled down, half of the text is cut off. I want to make an offset or something, so there is a little whitespace at the top of the screen above the text, like this:

[image]

Currently, it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Line height maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
scrollTop: target.offset().top - target.height()
```

To let a little space at top...

---

**Or** you could do something like (*not sure, need to be tested*):

```
var video = target.next() // considering that is the video block
var centerizeHeight = $(window).height() - (target.height() + video.height()) 
centerizeHeight = (centerizeHeight > 0) centerizeHeight : 1
//...
scrollTop: target.offset().top - (centerizeHeight/2)
```

Note: be sure your doctype is in your page

Comment: The first one worked, but I need it to be a little larger of a space. How do I do that, and what does this snippet actually do?

Comment: This is what it looks like now. [Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/N52AJvZ.png) Should it work just by putting it in <script> tags?

Comment: Same problem as before, see my above comment.

Comment: I ll take a look this night, see you

Comment: can you share the part of code with a title and a video ?

Comment: This is the code:`<h2 id="happywheels">Happy Wheels</h2>
                    <div class="games preview" style="width: 72vw; height: 40vw; background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url('/thumbnails/HappyWheels.png');">
                        <img class="swf play" src="/templates/images/PlayButton.png" size="width: 72vw; height: 40vw;" url="/games/HappyWheels.swf">
                    </div>`